# How extract values of dictionary column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on VCF file format,after getting data in pandas dataframe i'm getting below output.

Code

```
df1=df['info_dict']
print df1
```

output-

```
chr1  2337185                                {u'END': 2337193}
      2337194 {u'IDS': u'1026660,1026661', u'CUR': u'UNKNOWN'}
      2337195                                {u'END': 2337293}
      2337903                                {u'END': 2338125}
      2338126{u'IDS': u'652130,652129', u'CUR': u'KNOWN_BEN...
      2338127                                {u'END': 2338414}
      2339871                                {u'END': 2340199}
```

I want to only get values of IDS which is in third column.

Expected output:

```
chr1  2337194 '1026660,1026661'
      2338126 '652130,652129'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.get` for get value from dict with default value `None` if non match, last remove `None`s by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
s = df['info_dict'].apply(lambda x: x.get('IDS')).dropna()
print (s)
chr1  2337194    1026660,1026661
      2338126      652130,652129
Name: col, dtype: object
```